# Local.xml seems not to remove blocks or LOAD at all

Tags: jquery, layout, themes, local, magento-1.9.1

I've been testing around with Magento for a while and I want to start themeing a bit.
I really getting annoyed by something I probably can't seem to get right.
I've been creating my own theme folders:

app/design/frontend/bi/default/
and
skin/design/frontend/bi/default/

Now when adding .phtml files to app/design/frontend/bi/default/templates it works like a charm.
Also when I'm changing a bit of css.
But when I try to remove blocks from my page it doesn't seem to work.(Magento 1.9 btw)

app/design/frontend/bi/default/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/> 
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout"/> 
    </default>
</layout>
```

I Can't seem to figure out what the problem is but when I turn on path hints in developer mode. The callout and paypal are still loaded. frontend/base/default/template/callouts/right_col.phtm for example is what the path says when loading the page.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

When I put `<remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>` in my payapal.xml default file it does in fact remove the paypal logo. But I would like to control this all in the local.xml file in which it is not working.

**EDIT2**

I changed the local.xml a bit to add jquery but that isn't including it either. It seems like the local.xml isn't loaded at all. Is this normal in magento-1.9.1 probably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be some "caracters" in de file that did not show up in my text editor. That's why the local.xml file was ignored.